# Backbone.js: Collection is undefined when using template

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I am currently trying to learn backbone.js on my own. I have looked at the tutorials such as Thomas Davis's @ https://backbonetutorials.com/ and youtube channels. I am trying to make a modular backbone application using require.js, underscore.js, text.js for rendering my templates, and jquery.

I am running into an issue where in my collections view, I am getting back a JSON object, but it's not rendering on the template. I have looked at numerous SO solutions, and so far, no dice.

**Backbone View (list.js)**

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'collections/Users',
'text!templates/user-list-template.html'],
function ($, _, Backbone, Users, UserListTemplate) {
    var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        render: function () {
            var that = this;
            that.collection = new Users();
            that.collection.fetch({
                success: function () {
                    var template = _.template(UserListTemplate,
                                     {users: that.collection.models});
                    that.$el.html(template);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return UserList;
});
```

**Collections (Users.js)**

```
define(['backbone', 'models/User'],
function (Backbone, User) {
    var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: User,
        url: 'restapiurl'
    });
    return Users;
});
```

**Template (user-list-template)**

```
<script type="text/template" id="user-list-template"> 
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= user.get('firstname') %></td>
                    <td><%= user.get('lastname') %></td>
                    <td><%= user.get('age') %></td>
                    <td><a href="#/edit/<%= user.get('id') %>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
            <% }); %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

Now, I am able to get to my REST service and pull back data from my database.
I invoke the `.fetch()` on my collections, I did a `console.log(that.collection.toJSON());` and on my JS console on chrome, I got my object.

According to the JS console, it breaks at the `that.$el.html(template);` line in my view. The message is :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: users is not defined
```

So, here's the thing. When I had everything on one page, that's including templates, javascripts and the sorts, everything worked. However, when I try to modularize this, it breaks. No clue.

I will appreciate all help.
Thanks.

Comment: You used to be able to say `h = _.template(tmpl, data)` but as of Underscore 1.7 you **must** do it in two steps: `t = _.template(tmpl); h = t(data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `_.template` method incorrectly. `_.template` compiles a string into a Javascript function that receives data and outputs HTML.

This should do the trick:

```
var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    template: _.template(UserListTemplate),
    initialize: function() {
        // collections are normally passed into views, but it's not a big deal
        this.collection = new Users();
        // when the collection gets data (sync), call render
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },
    render: function () {
        var data = { users: this.collection.models },
            html = this.template(data);

        this.$el.html(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, you can't compile-and-execute Underscore templates anymore, that stopped working in Underscore 1.7. So they end up giving the template function to jQuery's [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which will execute a function if you give it one but it won't give the template function the arguments that it is expecting.

Comment: Okay. Sorry for taking so long to replay. This works. I no longer get that error message (thank you so much on that). However, it does not render the template on the page. Is this what @muistooshort was talking about? Thanks!!

Comment: @JasonCidras: I'm talking about saying `_.template(tmpl, data)` in one go, that doesn't work anymore. Did you get the rendering sorted out? I'll re-open if there's more going on that just the template issue.

Comment: Perhaps the `.page` element does not exist on the page when this view is created? As a best practice, you should pass the element to the view when creating it. ie: `new View({ el: $('.page') });` and also may want to use an ID selector, because there could be multiple `.page` elements.

Comment: To be honest, I just gave up. I don't know why it wasn't working. Then I kept on getting requirejs errors. It was just frustrating.

Comment: I'm going to guess at why it wasn't working. I believe that I was using the latest libraries and frameworks of javascripts and they just didn't play nice together... requirejs - 2.1, jquery-2.1.3, underscore-1.8.3, backbone-1.1.2. With all of those referenced, I think they were just fighting with each other. However, I reverted back to one page and I am using backbone-0.9.2, jquery-1.8.2, and underscore 1.4.2. This works. Later, after I gather my sanity, I'll attempt it again with those libraries.

Comment: @muistooshort, I finally got my templates working. I removed the script tags on my templates. Also, I am using backbone 0.9.2, jquery 1.8.2, and underscore 1.4.2. Everything is now working. Thanks!!

Comment: @JasonCidras: That makes sense, I think require.js is just looking for plain old unadorned text when you say `text!` so the `<script>`s would end up in the template and inserting a `<script>` into the page wouldn't display anything.